# How to plot density curve with different variable in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame that have the variables "necrosis" and "angles". I want to plot a density curve where I have the density of necrosis for each angle. For example in the figure below I was able to plot the frequency using the following code:

First, I created a frequency table, you can access the data frame here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/duynpb3n9nh8epc/filter_df.csv?dl=0

```
table_fq <- table(filter_df$necrosis, filter_df$angles,
                  dnn = c("necrosis", "angles"))

    #transform the table into data frame
     df_fire <- as.data.frame(table_fq)
```

When I transform the table into data frame some variables were not numeric so I just transformed to numeric using this code:

```
 df_fire$angles <- as.numeric(as.character(df_fire$angles))
 df_fire$Freq <- as.numeric(as.character(df_fire$Freq))
 df_fire$necrosis <- as.numeric(as.character(df_fire$necrosis))
```

In also removed the frequencies equal to 0 from the data frame

```
 # Filter out any rows with zero frequency
 df <- df_fire[df_fire$Freq > 0,]
```

Using this code I plotted the frequency vs angles

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = angles)) +
   geom_col(aes(y = Freq), alpha = 0.5) +
   labs(x = "angles", y = "Frequency") +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360), breaks = seq(0, 360, 40)) +
   xlab(bquote("Tree stem angles" (theta))) +
   theme_bw()
```

and this is the figure.

[image]

But now I am trying to do a similar plot but with density plot. So far I only found how to plot one variable (x-axis) and density (y-axis). But what I am trying to do is exactly the same thing I did for the frequency where x-axis is the angles and y-axis the necrosis density. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

`length(unique(df$angles))` returns 180. Do you really want 180 densities in one plot? If yes, here is a way. To have one density per value of `angles`, assign an aesthetic to that variable, in the case below I have assigned it to `fill`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
})

path <- "~/Temp"
fl <- "filter_df.csv"

filter_df <- read.csv(file.path(path, fl))

table_fq <- table(filter_df$necrosis, filter_df$angles,
                  dnn = c("necrosis", "angles"))

#transform the table into data frame
df_fire <- as.data.frame(table_fq)
df_fire$necrosis <- as.integer(as.character(df_fire$necrosis))
# Filter out any rows with zero frequency
df <- df_fire[df_fire$Freq > 0, ]

length(unique(df$angles))
#> [1] 180

ggplot(df, aes(necrosis, fill = angles)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE)
#> Warning: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.
#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Noting that most angles are present in only 2 to 4 rows, for a total of 168 rows with less than 5 equal angles, you can make the plot easier to read by grouping the angles. Below I group in steps of 50.

```r
sum(table(df$angles) < 5)
#> [1] 168

grouped <- (as.integer(as.character(df$angles)) %/% 50L) * 50L
df$angles_grouped <- factor(grouped)
levels(df$angles_grouped)
#> [1] "0"   "50"  "100" "150" "200" "250" "300" "350"

ggplot(df, aes(necrosis, fill = angles_grouped)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density)), alpha = 0.3) +
  labs(fill = "Grouped angles")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A solution to consider is to plot the densities at different heights. This can be done with package [`ggridges`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggridges).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggridges)
})

ggplot(df, aes(necrosis, y = angles_grouped)) +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  labs(fill = "Grouped angles") +
  theme_bw()
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.703
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>